# Additional dimension in multidimensional array after assigning to new variable

Tags: php

I have a function that returns a 2 dimensional array ($user $door $ result are arrays too):

```
function test() {
    $erg = array ($user, $door, $result);       
    return($erg);
}
```

Now in the script I call the function and try to assign it to a new variable:

```
        $myarray test();
        echo $myarray[0]['id'];
```

This throws an exception: Index not defined: 'id'. When I add a dimension it works:

```
        echo $myarray[0][0]['id'];
```

I dont know where this 2nd dimenstion comes from :-(

Comment: Can you give us teh code for `$user`/etc., too?

Comment: In very short: Debug. Have a look at `$user` (and probably `$door` and `$result` too). If you don't use a debugger (you should), `var_dump()` can already help. However, I doubt anybody can help you, because I assume, that this dimension is already in `$user` and because it appears out of nowhere nobody can tell just by looking at it :)

Comment: $user comes from a database request. I didnt think on this variant yet :)
$user = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: That could be the problem - $user is a multi-dimensional array already (for example there's $user[0]['id'], $user[1]['id'] etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line:

```
$erg = array ($user, $door, $result);
```

indexes your arrays given by the order provided.

So this actually becomes:

```
$erg = array ("0"=>$user, "1"=>$door, "2"=>$result);
```

So either your $user array is similar to:

```
$user = array("0"=>array("id","userid"));
```

or you call this function several times and every time you call that function it adds a new parent index[0] to the provided array.